# How to get number of lines added and deleted to/form the code in Gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

Imagine a code is being developed by different contributor. How to calculate the number of lines added and deleted to/from the code in Gerrit?

Comment: Do you want to know the number of lines added and deleted in a single change (commit)?

Comment: In a single change as well as for all the commits...

Answer (score 2):

Gerrit shows the number of lines added and deleted in the change page, in front of the files names:

[image]

You can see the same info for all commits by changing the patchset number.

Comment: how can i see the changes in terms of lines made by the each contributor?

Comment: All changes are done by the same contributor (the change owner), aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question was meant to ask about repository code stats.
If so, try gerritstats:
https://github.com/holmari/gerritstats

Demo
A demo of the resulting HTML output is available at:

http://gerritstats-demo.firebaseapp.com